# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/glxn/qrgen/QRCode

Tags: servlets, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to generate QRcode in eclipse with servlet

Get Following Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/glxn/qrgen/QRCode
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:689)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have all the libraries in your web application. Place QRcode library in your web project's `WEB-INF/lib` folder.
  The problem of `NoClassDefFoundError` occurs when the class definition is not found at runtime.

It could be the case that the library is present in eclipse at compile time so compilation is successful. But when you deploy application on server then you need to have all the required libraries with the app.